# Excel File is not being locked by a certain user

Tags: windows-7, storage-area-network, microsoft-office-2013

I have a file on a network storage. That file gets locked when its in use by somebody else, except by one person. I had about 5 people test it, and only one user does not get the File is locked, read-only copy error. That one person is able to make changes while the file is opened else where. That file is very sensitive and needs to be locked whenever its in use.

Can anyone point me to the right direction to make sure the file is locked too everyone while its in use??

Comment: 1. Have you checked the sharing settings inside the excel file? 2. Have you checked this with the same user but different computer?

Comment: Did you check whether the user in question is opening the workbook read-only? Either by choice or if they only have read-only access to the workbook or folder. EliadTech has the other answer - look over the user's shoulder when they have the workbook open and click "Share Workbook" on the Review tab. The checkbox should be unchecked.

Comment: I have checked the share settings, NOT checked to allow changes by more then one users. I have checked on another computer (2 in fact), still not getting locked message.The user is not opening in read-only because they can make changes to the file on network drive.

Comment: i've tried creating new documents, and different types (excel, word), and the issue is the same. For some reason that user can't get locked out the file. I've tried removing permissions, not including inheritable permissions, problem still persist. Ideas anyone? Keep in mind i'm testing the same with a different user account, and that account does get the locked message.

Comment: "I have a file on a network storage." - please clarify.  Where is the file?

Comment: The file is located on a network drive (SAN)